# ASP.NET MVC app execute first the post and not the get

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, sharepoint

I have an Sharepoint provider hosted app with MCV project, the main page is an App Part with 2 index actions, one get and one post. The problem is that in the first page load the validation is happening when the user has not even started to fill the form because it goes to the post controller directly and not to the get

The idea is that in the index get I should get the view, and in the post, the form will be submitted.

View:

```
@using (@Html.BeginForm("Solicitar", "RegistroDeSolicitudes", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Cabana, new { @class = "col-xs-6 col-sm-3" })
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
                <select name="Cabana">
                    <option value="C1">Cabaña 1</option>
                    <option value="C2">Cabaña 2</option>
                    <option value="C3">Cabaña 3</option>
                    <option value="C4">Cabaña 4</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Cedula, new { @class = "col-xs-6 col-sm-3" })
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Cedula)
            </div>
            <div>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Cedula)</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Nombres, new { @class = "col-xs-6 col-sm-3" })
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Nombres)
            </div>
            <div>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Nombres)
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Apellidos, new { @class = "col-xs-6 col-sm-3" })
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Apellidos)
            </div>
            <div>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Apellidos)
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, new { @class = "col-xs-6 col-sm-3" })
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email)
            </div>
            <div>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email)
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FechaDesde, new { @class = "col-xs-6 col-sm-3" })
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FechaDesde)
            </div>
            <div>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FechaDesde)
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FechaHasta, new { @class = "col-xs-6 col-sm-3" })
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FechaHasta)
            </div>
            <div>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FechaHasta)
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3" id="stylesheet"></div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
                <input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Controller:

```
public class RegistroDeSolicitudesController : Controller
{
    [SharePointContextFilter]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Title = "Registro de Solicitudes";
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [SharePointContextFilter]
    public ActionResult Index([Bind(Include = "Cabana,Cedula,Nombres,Apellidos,Email,FechaDesde,FechaHasta")] Reserva reserva)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                var spContext = SharePointContextProvider.Current.GetSharePointContext(HttpContext);

                using (var cc = spContext.CreateUserClientContextForSPHost())
                {
                    reserva.Estado = "Pendiente";
                    Helpers.SaveSolicitud(cc, reserva);
                }
                HttpContext.Session["PrimeraVez"] = "no";
                TempData["UserMessage"] = "Su solicitud ha sido registrada exitosamente";
                TempData["AlertClass"] = "alert-success";
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                TempData["UserMessage"] = "Lo sentimos, ha ocurrido un error. Intenta de nuevo";
                TempData["AlertClass"] = "alert-danger";
            }
        }
        ViewBag.Title = "Registro de Solicitudes";
        return View();
    }

}
```

Model:

```
 public class Reserva
{
    [Display(Name = "Cabaña")]
    [StringLength(2, MinimumLength = 2)]
    public string Cabana { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Cédula")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Por favor escriba su cédula")]
    public int Cedula { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Por favor escriba sus Nombres")]
    [StringLength(60, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "Por favor escriba un valor válido para este campo")]
    public string Nombres { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Por favor escriba sus Apellidos")]
    [StringLength(60, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "Por favor escriba un valor válido para este campo")]
    public string Apellidos { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Por favor escriba un correo electrónico")]
    [StringLength(60, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "Por favor escriba un correo válido")]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Fecha desde")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Por favor escriba una fecha")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime FechaDesde { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Fecha Hasta")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Por favor escriba una fecha")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime FechaHasta { get; set; }

    public string Estado { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `return View()` to

```
 return RedirectToAction("Index", new { SPHostUrl = SharePointContext.GetSPHostUrl(HttpContext.Request).AbsoluteUri });
```

Comment: Thank you so much!, I add the return and change the name of post action method